# How to use "this" keyword inside a fetch API call result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, fetch-api

I'm using the following fetch API to get an API result. I need to set the result data in the state but the "this" object is unavailable inside the callback function. How can I update the code to set the value in the state by accessing the `this` keyword?

```
fetch(config.apiUrl + '/api/user', {
  headers: authHeader(),
  method: 'GET',
})
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    this.setState({ id: data.id });
  });
```

Comment: This question is tagged with react-redux, so if you're using Redux, it's unusual to be mutating state in this manner. In Redux, you would likely be concatenating new state to the global state store in a reducer, not mutating in-context UI React state (this). Redux solves the context complications that arise by using 'this' as a mutable state store. Not an answer, just an observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Assign `this` keyword to a variable that's outside the callback where it is still available. Often `var self = this;` is used.
- Use 'self' in the callback where you need it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use arrow functions

```
fetch(config.apiUrl + '/api/user', {
  headers: authHeader(),
  method: 'GET',
})
  .then(res => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({ id: data.id });
  });
```

or you can assign the `this` keyword to a variable and use that like 
`var that = this;`

```
fetch(config.apiUrl + '/api/user', {
  headers: authHeader(),
  method: 'GET',
})
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    that.setState({ id: data.id });
  });
```