# How to get the value from previous value in json using fetch api?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch-api

On react native i got the value from key but can't get value from previous value.
for example i have following json

```
{
"username":"xyz",
"xyz":{"role":3,"role_name":"abcd"}
}
```

i need to get username and using the username value need to access role. I have tried following.

```
 constructor(){
    this.state={rol:'role',uname:'',xtext:'',}
}

  fetch('example.com/url')
  .then(response =>  response.json())
  .then(responseobj => {
    this.setState({
      uname: responseobj.username,
     xtest: responseobj[this.state.uname][this.state.rol],
   });
```

i got the username but not the role.

Comment: Show the usage context of the `fetch`.  Is it in a method?  That `constructor` is within a `class` no doubt, can you show more of the `class`?

Comment: This is similar to a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50523225/how-to-use-this-keyword-inside-a-fetch-api-call-result this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState is async, so state is not ready yet, you can use this:

```
  then(responseobj => {
    this.setState({
      uname: responseobj.username,
      xtest: responseobj[responseobj.username][this.state.rol],
   });
```

or if you really want to use state, you use the callback:

```
  then(responseobj => {
    this.setState({
      uname: responseobj.username,
   }, () => {
     this.setState({
       xtest: responseobj[this.state.uname][this.state.rol],
     })
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because this.state.uname is an empty string when you are trying to use it in the setState function. `setState` is setting both values simultaneously. Try this:

```
    this.setState({
     uname: responseobj.username,
     xtest: responseobj[responseobj.username][this.state.rol],
   });
```

Comment: True, but in the example provided above this.state.uname === '' so it wont do what Shibin Raju Mathew is trying to achieve

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50523225/how-to-use-this-keyword-inside-a-fetch-api-call-result or check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50766042/7622397

Comment: With all respect, try to read me here. I have never said that you cant get existing state from within setState. The answer you are referring to had to save this to a variable since they were using setState from within regular functions and not, in our case, arrow functions (which auto binds this to the class).